# How to validate if a user input is both a float and with a given range in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to validate a user input to check if it is both a number (float) and within a range (0-1).  I have used Try except to check if the input is a float as below:

```
while True:
    try:
        rate=input(": ")
        rate=float(rate)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("That was not a valid numerical value, please try again")
```

This works for checking if the input is numerical (floats are accepted) however I cannot make it check both if its numerical and within a range (0,1) this needs to return the rate to my main code.

I am able to validate if an input is within a range I just can't work out how to do both checks so that for example if a user enters 3.8 they get and error message and are able to re-input if they then put a string it would not crash the code.

Comment: *" if a user enters 3.8 they get and error message and are able to re-input"* currently, that isn't what's happening with the code you have provided.

Comment: @Jim I think they know that.... The full sentence reads *"I just can't work out how to do both checks so that for example if a user enters 3.8 they get and error message and are able to re-input if they then put a string it would not crash the code."*

Answer (score 3):

You can consider using `try-except-else` in the following manner:

```
min_val = 1
max_val = 10
while True:
    rate = input(": ")
    try:
        rate = float(rate)
    except ValueError:
        print("That was not a valid numerical value, please try again")
    else:
        if min_val < rate < max_val:
            break
        else:
            print("This number is not in the required range")
```

This will require the input to be a number in the range `min_val < rate < max_val`. Note that the `else` block is executed only if no `exception` was raised.

Another approach would be to use the already catched `ValueError` to raise your own:

```
min_val = 1
max_val = 10
while True:
    rate = input(": ")
    try:
        rate = float(rate)
        if not min_val < rate < max_val:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print("That was not a valid numerical value, please try again")
    else:
        break
```